# Technology use in real time chat like wechat android and ios

Tags: android, ios, real-time

I wondering any solution to make an real time chat like wechat or whatsapp. I having researching but most of them are just mention use 3rd parties server. I already have my LEMP server setup so I would like to use my own server instead of 3rd parties.

I mean if I have 10K download my app from either google or app store. I want them be able chat with one another in real time just like whatsapp. How can I let them retreive the new data that send by another user in real time without using any library or 3rd parties such as XMPP, PUSHER or PARSE?

Sorry for my grammar error. Any Suggestion apperciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup your web server communication could be done in real time web sockets https://www.websocket.org/ . You could send and receive messages in json formats . Also have a look at Stomp http://stomp.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Websocket related solution.

Try [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) or [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). They are both easy to implementation similar function and are also scalable.